# Having labels in a Web view

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, scrollbar

I have a web view into which I am loading a local HTML string. I also have a few labels that will be in the same view as the web view. The problem is that when I scroll, it only scrolls through the web view, and not the labels, i.e. the labels stay in place and the web view keeps scrolling. How can I make the labels (which are above the web view) part of the scrolling process ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add a UILabel as a child view of UIWebView. One way you could get around this and solve your problem is by implementing the scrollViewDidScroll method for you UIWebView and monitoring the content offset of the UIWebView.

By updating the UILabel constraints relative to the content offset you will be able to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: tell me more please :) If I add them (how?) as subviews of my web view, will they automatically be affected by the scrolling process ?

Comment: The UILabels do not need to be children of your UIWebView, you can simply observe the scroll position of the UIWebView and update the position of your UILabels accordingly.

Comment: That seems to make sense. Could you help me out with the actual code required for this ?

Comment: You should be able to find good answers on Stack Overflow to help you with implementing my suggested method. If you get stuck just ask another question. Thanks